# MLE of simultaneous exponential distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution, fisher-information

Given the $X_i\sim \text{exp}({\theta})$ and $Y_i\sim \text{exp}(\frac{1}{\theta})$, where $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are indpendent, with the same $\theta>0$. I have to find the MLE and its distribution.

I find the simultaneous distribution to be:
$$f_{X_i,Y_i}(x,y)=e^{-\left(\frac{x_i}{\theta }+\theta  y_i\right)}1_{(0,\infty )}(x_i)1_{(0,\infty )}(y_i),$$
and the Fisherinformation:
$$i_n(\theta)=\frac{2 n}{\theta ^2}$$

As it's convex, the maximum of the loglikelihood must be a minima, so I find the MLE:
$$\hat{\theta}=\left(\frac{X_{\bullet }}{Y_{\bullet }}\right)^{0.5},$$
where $X_{\bullet }=\sum _{i=1}^n x_i$ and $Y_{\bullet }=\sum _{i=1}^n y_i$. So the asymptotic distribution is:
$$\hat{\theta}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\theta ,\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right),$$
as $\hat{\theta}\approx\mathcal{N}\left(\theta,\frac{1}{ni_n(\theta)}\right),$
where $i_\theta$ is the Fisherinformation.

I am in doubt whether this is the right procedure.

---

**EDIT**

It is the right procedure - my professor provided the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a sample of $n$ observations on $(X_i,Y_i)$, the likelihood function given $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ is

\begin{align}
L(\theta)&=\prod_{i=1}^n e^{-\left(x_i/\theta+\theta y_i\right)}\mathbf1_{x_i>0,y_i>0}
\\&=\exp\left[{-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{x_i}{\theta}+\theta y_i\right)}\right]\mathbf1_{x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n>0}
\\&=\exp\left[-\frac{n\bar x}{\theta}-\theta n\bar y\right]\mathbf1_{x_{(1)},y_{(1)}>0}\quad,\,\theta>0
\end{align}

This, as you say, yields the MLE $$\hat\theta(\mathbf X,\mathbf Y)=\sqrt{\frac{\overline X}{\overline Y}}$$, where $\overline X,\overline Y$ are the sample means.

Now $X_i$'s are i.i.d $\mathsf{Exp}$ with mean $\theta$, and $Y_i$'s are i.i.d $\mathsf{Exp}$ with mean $1/\theta$, where $X_i,Y_i$ are independent.

Or, $$\frac{2}{\theta}X_i\stackrel{\text{ i.i.d }}\sim\chi^2_2\quad,\text{ independent of }\quad2\theta Y_i\stackrel{\text{ i.i.d }}\sim\chi^2_2$$

Therefore summing over the observations, we have

$$\frac{2}{\theta}n\overline X\sim\chi^2_{2n}\quad,\text{ independent of }\quad 2\theta n\overline Y\sim\chi^2_{2n}$$

Taking ratio of the statistics gives $$\frac{\overline X}{\theta^2 \overline Y}\sim F_{2n,2n}$$

So the (exact) distribution of the MLE $\hat\theta$ can be expressed as $$\frac{\hat\theta}{\theta}\stackrel{d}{=} \sqrt F\quad,\text{ where }F\sim F_{2n,2n}$$

---

Since by (weak) law of large numbers $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\stackrel{P}\longrightarrow E(X_1)=\theta$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i\stackrel{P}\longrightarrow E(Y_1)=\frac{1}{\theta}$,

$$\hat\theta^2=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i}\stackrel{P}\longrightarrow \frac{E(X_1)}{E(Y_1)}=\theta^2$$

And by continuous mapping theorem, $$\hat\theta \stackrel{P}\longrightarrow \theta$$

This further implies convergence in distribution. So as one might expect, the asymptotic distribution of $\hat\theta$ is degenerate at $\theta$.

---

Asymptotic normality of MLE is a general result which holds under some  smoothness assumptions of the population density. These so called regularity conditions are sufficient conditions for verifying asymptotic normality. If these conditions hold, then indeed a non-degenerate limiting distribution of MLE is given by

$$\sqrt n\left(\hat\theta-\theta\right)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N\left(0,\frac1{I(\theta)}\right)\,,$$

where $I(\theta)$ is the Fisher information contained in a single observation.

For a direct proof of asymptotic normality in this particular problem, see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/405431/119261) answer.

Alternatively, we can use the multivariate central limit theorem combined with the delta method to reach the same answer.

By CLT we have

$$\sqrt n\left(\left(\overline X,\overline Y\right)-\left(\theta,\frac1{\theta}\right)\right)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N\left(\mathbf 0,\Sigma\right)\,,$$

where $$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\theta^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac1{\theta^2}\end{pmatrix}$$

By the [delta-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method), the following holds for some function $g$ :

$$\sqrt n\left(g\left(\overline X,\overline Y\right)-g\left(\theta,\frac1{\theta}\right)\right)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N\left( 0, \nabla g\left(\theta,\frac1{\theta}\right)^T \cdot \Sigma \cdot \nabla g\left(\theta,\frac1{\theta}\right)\right)$$

Taking $g(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac xy}$ for $x,y>0$, this reduces to

$$\sqrt n\left(\hat\theta-\theta\right)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N\left(0,\frac{\theta^2}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, @StubbornAtom. Am I correct if I say, that the asymptotic distribution for the $\hat{\theta}$ is correct? Have you any advice in regards to knowing when the asymptotic approach is not best?

Comment: I understand your concern, however, the reason I am looking for the asymptotic distribution is that I am solving an old exam set. In this set, they want me to find MLE, as I have, and the asymptotic distribution hereof - even though finding the exact distribution would be better.

I have found the asymptotic distribution with formula:
$$\hat{\theta}\approx\mathcal{N}\left(\theta,\hat{\text{se}}^2\right)=\mathcal{N}\left(\theta,\frac{1}{I_n(\theta)}\right),$$
from "All of Statistics" on p. 129.

Comment: @Frederik Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you, @StubbornAtom. I will try to look into it, as I'm not that familiar with the understanding of the way that MLE can degenerate.