# Asymptotic distribution of MLE of joint exponential distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution, delta-method

Given $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{Exp}(\theta)$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n \sim \text{Exp}(\frac{1}{\theta})$, where $\theta>0$ and have the same $\theta$ in both distributions. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I have found the MLE of the simultaneous distribution: 
$$\hat{\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{X_{\bullet}}{Y_{\bullet}}},$$
where $X_\bullet=\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}$ and $Y_\bullet=\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i}$.

I know that I can find the exact distribution, which is:
$$\hat{\theta}\theta^{-1}\sim \sqrt{F},\quad\quad F\sim F_{2n,2n},$$
however, my professor insist that I has to find the asymptotic distribution of the MLE. Please see the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3193975/493634), where the focus were on why the asymptotic solution not were the best, however, I still has to find it.

I thought that I could use CLT in combination with the Delta Method, but I really don't see a proper fit.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

This question was part of an old exam set at my university, and the professor who made the exam set (whom don't work as a professor today), have provided me with the official solution, which he still had:

As in the linked question, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3193975/493634), I had found the correct asymptotic distribution. It is:

$$\hat{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\theta,(ni_\theta)^{-1}\right),$$
where $i_\theta$ is the Fisherinformation.

Comment: Thank you, @StubbornAtom. I misunderstood what it meant that it degenerated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MLE of simultaneous exponential distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193796/mle-of-simultaneous-exponential-distributions)